# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #9

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

**LIVE STREAM!**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuDG_xeS2lI

The 9th Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! This meetup is going to be a special one! 3 presentations with 3 presenters from 3 countries! They will talk about the following topics:

**1. Sitecore Cortex: From Introduction to Extension - Jason Wilkerson (@Wilkerson Consulting & Sitecore MVP)**

> Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence are all the rage in buzz
>   words these days and Marketers are eagerly searching for ways to
>   incorporate this new landscape of technology into their customer's
>   journeys. Cortex may be the answer to that search! In this session,
>   we'll talk about Sitecore Cortex, its out-of-the-box functionality, as
>   well as how you might leverage it today. We'll also discuss how and
>   when you might extend it to achieve additional business goals through
>   automation, including custom workers and agents.

**2. How to personalize the user experience with offline data from Sitecore Universal Tracker - Akshay Sura (@Konabos & Sitecore MVP)**

> In this presentation we will go through how a fictitious conference company is able to personalize the content on their Sitecore site based on the information they gather from offline sources such as IoT RFID scanners at the conferences, external sites built in PHP and HTML.

**3. Customizing Sitecore SXA - Peter Procházka (@Accenture & Sitecore MVP)**

> Peter will introduce you to the world of Sitecore SXA and then he will continue the talk with some customizations and tweaks that he and his team did to make it work for them and fulfill all their requirements.

Free conversations, food and drink after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Friday, September 27, 2019 6:00 PM

**Where:** POSSIBLE CEE Budapest, Bocskai út 134-146. Budapest, Hungary 1113

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/264053922/)**